# Is there a nicer way to split a user input at a specific character, add everything before it to a list, then the character, then continue repeating?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to create a "math interpreter" just for fun. So first step should probably be converting user input into a format I can easily work with. Now, I got it working, it's splitting everything as expected, but I have a feeling that there's a much much much more simple way of doing it. Here's what I have:

Main function:

```py
def main():

    userInput:str = input("What problem would you like solved?\nProblem: ")

    str_build:str = ""
    problem_list:list = []

    index:int = 0

    while(index < len(userInput)):
        curr_char:str = userInput[index]

        if checkForSign(curr_char) == False:
            str_build += curr_char
        else:

            if str_build != "":
                problem_list.append(str_build)

            problem_list.append(curr_char)
            str_build = ""

        index += 1

    print(problem_list)

    return 0
```

And the one that checks for operands:

```py
def checkForSign(character: str) -> bool:
    match character:
        case "+":
            return True
        case "-":
            return True
        case "/":
            return True
        case "*":
            return True
        case _:
            return False
```

So lets say the user inputs
`10+2*5-534/2`

Then the preferred output should be
`['10', '+', '2', '*', '5', '-', '534', '/', '2']`

So far I've tried regex (not much success there, but I was curios about it). Code works, I do get a nicer arrangement of the inputs, but there has to be a shorter, maybe more efficient way of doing it.

Edit:
Atm it can't really do anything when it's presented with a negative number, so preferably I'd like to be able to work with those too.

Comment: The way you do this will depend on whether you need to account for both positive and negative integer and floating point numbers. Your example is showing only positive integers.

Comment: @CtrlZ for now I only want to worry about greater than 0., but that's true, I should've probably thought about negative integers. the way I currently do it, allows for it, with a little bit of reworking. So yeah. I'll edit it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is solely concerned with positive integers then:

```
ui = input("What problem would you like solved? ")

result = [""]

for c in ui:
    if c.isdecimal():
        result[-1] += c
    elif c in "+-*/":
        result.extend([c, ""])
    else:
        print("Invalid formula")
        break
else:
    print(result)
```

For an input of 10+2*5-534/2 this will output:

```
['10', '+', '2', '*', '5', '-', '534', '/', '2']
```